# Viewing windows for plot (graphing question)

Tags: plotting

I have to plot two curves against each other with viewing windows `[0,100]` by `[0,1]`. I can get the `x` axis to 100, but how do I do it with the `y` axis going to one?

For reference, here is my current script:

```
Plot[{(1/x^1.1), (1/x^.9)}, {x, 0, 100}]
```

Thank you!! I am still new to Mathematica and can't figure it out!!

Comment: Try `Plot[{(1/x^1.1), (1/x^.9)}, {x, 0, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 10}}]` and lookup dokumentation `PlotRange` for more detials

Comment: You might want to look at using `LogPlot`